# ValueError: The 'ydata_profiling' package was not installed in a way that PackageLoader understands

Tags: python, jinja2, pyinstaller

i compiled an APP use `**Pyinstaller**` and got this error popup when open the compiled .exe file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myuniverse.py", line 133, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ydata_profiling\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ydata_profiling\compare_reports.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ydata_profiling\profile_report.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ydata_profiling\report\presentation\flavours\html\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ydata_profiling\report\presentation\flavours\html\alerts.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ydata_profiling\report\presentation\flavours\html\templates.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 323, in __init__
ValueError: The 'ydata_profiling' package was not installed in a way that PackageLoader understands.
```

NOT WORK:

- Add ydata_profiling path in Pyinstaller cmd `-p=""`
- Add 'Initializing Jinja' code block like in [this page](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/issues/942) to ydata_profiling **init** file source

Answer (score 1):

According to the package issues it seems like it is not yet possible to install ydata-profiling with *pyinstaller*.

The package works template files and that seems to be causing issues. There is a suggested bypass to the issue though (https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/issues/942)